What's the best way to recover silver from industrial and medical x-ray film?
I washed industrial and medical x-ray film with lye and tap water. Can I add bleach to draw the silver out of the lye or would I just add salt water to get AgCl, then siphon off the excess water and wash with hot water, catch in filter, and finally melt in crucible with borax to obtain metallic silver?

I added tags for both home-experiment and industrial-chemistry. Sounds like you are attempting this in a "basement lab"? Beware waste handling and safety issues as pointed  out in the current answer. You don't want to turn your backyard into a superfund site.

radiopaedia.org describes the approach usually taken by the industry with

The commonest process now used is called "wash". The film is shredded and placed in large baths of a chemical reagent e.g. cyanide solution. The cyanide leaches the silver from the film. The silver is then removed from the solution by electrolysis.
The plastic substrate, usually polyethylene terephthalate (PET), can then be recycled.
References

Masebinu SO, Muzenda E. Review of silver recovery techniques from radiographic effluent and X-ray film waste. Proceedings of the World Congress on Engineering and Computer Science 2014 Vol II WCECS 2014, 22-24 October, 2014, San Francisco, USA http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCECS2014/WCECS2014_pp613-617.pdf


as a process highly efficient in recovery of Ag, and use of electrochemistry.  However, the management of cyanide solutions in general, and of the parameters of an electrolysis (potential, charge density, temperature, perhaps use of some additives to adjust pH value and conductivity, etc.) are better left to trained personnel with proper safety equipment.
Depending on locale, the use of X-ray films (including their wet chemistry) fades out (or already is gone for long) in favor of digital technology with basically instantaneous access to the data in a machine readable format with e.g., CCD/CMOS detectors, or «electronic plates» put behind/underneath the patient and read out after recording the exposure.  (A wide dynamic range (think 16bit, or or higher resolution) in a .tiff format, ease of zoom and background correction, rapid share via e-mail etc. are conveniences a film can't offer.)  In this perspective, human and veterinary diagnostics are not that different to e.g., powder or single crystal diffraction analysis in material science.

The current price of silver is ~US\$0.95 per gram, or ~US\$1,000/kg. According to Specialty Metals, "10 pounds of medical x-ray film usually contains about one Troy Ounce of silver," about 6 g Ag/kg film.
If you can obtain 10 kg of film, there would be about 60 g of silver in it, worth about US$60, if 100% were extracted. Could you purchase the chemicals to recover that silver, process the film, and dispose of the waste, and still make a profit?
Consider some other issues, too.

Washing the gelatin emulsion in $\ce{NaOH}$ may hydrolyze only part of it, and requires high temperatures. It is also quite dangerous.
Metallic silver does not react with $\ce{NaCl}$.
$\ce{Ag +NaOCl}$ yields $\ce{Ag2O}$. How would separate that from the solution, and what would it cost?

